# how to get gmail inbox messages through api in php?

Tags: php, api, import, gmail, message

Actually i followed the steps that given by google . 
      (Source : https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php )

But Finally i execute quickstart.php through terminal , then i got only Labels Names Not messages .i Received output like this ...

Labels:

```
- CATEGORY_UPDATES
- UNREAD
- DRAFT
- CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS
- INBOX
- CATEGORY_SOCIAL
- CATEGORY_PERSONAL
- CATEGORY_FORUMS
- TRASH
- CHAT
- IMPORTANT
- SENT
- STARRED
- SPAM
```

i don't know what to do further to get inbox messages ..

[image]

Can anyone please guide me.
also tell me if any other methods to get gmail messages and hangouts messages..
thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't post a link to an image, either insert it in the question, or better, paste the text in a block in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but maybe this helps someone

```
    $optParams = array(
        "labelIds" => $mailbox,
        "maxResults" => $maxMsgs,
    );
    $resultMessages = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($user, $optParams);
```